# Saving Android App Condition

Tags: java, android, save, conditional-statements

I am pretty new to Android / Java App development and wanted to ask,
the best way to save the app condition.
In my case I have two buttons, which have a default color of red.
When the user clicks on each of them it gets the color of blue.
What's the best way to save this condition?
So that the color will not reset to the color of red when I restart the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html).

Principal data storage options in Android:

- Saving key-value pairs of simple data types in a shared preferences
  file
- Saving arbitrary files in Android's file system
- Using databases managed by SQLite